# Problems setting FirstResponder in Cocoa Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, first-responder, becomefirstresponder

Im working on a tiny app just to learn cocoa, and Im having a hard time with setting FirstResponder to some NSTextFields.

When the view opens, I want the first NSTextField, clientNumber, to be selected, so I trigger [clientNumber becomeFirstResponder] at the end of my loadView method, but it does not select the text field.
But when I click the button that fires the (IBAction)addToArray method, it selects the right text field. Further do I have another text field, it should contain integers only, so I have a crude verification for it. When the content is not a int, I get a beep, just like it should, but it does not select the text field.

Here is my code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
      NSLog(@"initWithNibName");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillLoad {
    NSLog(@"viewWillLoad");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    [self initNewInvoice];    
}

- (void)loadView {
    NSLog(@"loadView");
    [self viewWillLoad];
    [super loadView];
    [self viewDidLoad];
    FakturaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FakturaAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    [appDelegate.window makeFirstResponder:self.clientNumber]; 
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib");
}

- (IBAction)saveInvoice:(id)sender
{
    FakturaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FakturaAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    [appDelegate.window makeFirstResponder:self.invoiceCredit]; 
}

- (IBAction)addToArray:(id)sender
{
    [clientNumber setStringValue: @"Toodeloo"];
    FakturaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FakturaAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    [appDelegate.window makeFirstResponder:self.clientNumber];  
}

- (IBAction)updateCreditDays:(id)sender
{
    if(invoiceCredit.intValue){
        [self updateCredit];
    }else{
        NSBeep();
        FakturaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FakturaAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    [appDelegate.window makeFirstResponder:self.invoiceCredit]; 
    }
}
```

I really hope someone can help me out here.

EDIT:

I got it all wrong, thanks for the pointers, but when I fix the code, using this:
    FakturaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FakturaAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    [appDelegate.window makeFirstResponder:self.invoiceCredit];
instead of becomeFirstResponder. But it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making this much harder than it needs to be.

In Interface Builder, set the `initialFirstResponder` outlet of your window to point to your text field.

That's it.

If you absolutely must do it programmatically, use:

```
[window setInitialFirstResponder:yourTextField];
```

Remember, if you're fighting with Cocoa to do something that seems like it should be simple, then you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: The text field is not loaded when the window opens at first. There are five different views that are loaded depending on which button the user clicks in the window. So thats why I have to set the focus to the appropriate text field later on.

Comment: Doesn't work with things like SplitViewControllers.  Set it programmatically in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 2):

Override viewDidAppear, and within said method, call the NSTextField's becomeFirstResponder method.

Note that in my own work, viewWillAppear has proven to be too early for said call, whether using the NSTextField's becomeFirstResponder method or the NSWindow's makeFirstResponder method.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that self.view.window is null in the first view controller's viewDidLoad method until after applicationDidFinishLaunching exits.  So, becomeFirstResponder doesn't work in viewDidLoad.  Try delaying the setting of the first responder, like so:

> [_yourTextField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)
>   withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

Answer (score 0):

You should never try to set first responder in **viewDidLoad** method because **window** is still nil at that point. Use viewWillAppear instead:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    [super viewWillAppear];
    if (!_started) {
        _started = YES;
        [self.view.window makeFirstResponder:_yourView];
    }
}
```

Apple also once said that you should never call becomeFirstResponder directly. Use **[yourWindow makeFirstResponder:yourView];** instead.

Comment: You are right.. This topic should have been closed long time ago, the question was relevant 6 years ago when it was posted. APIs are different now, and this would be the wrong approach anyway. ;)

Comment: I just added this answer to help other guys with Cocoa issues.

Answer (score -1):

Just read the documentation:

> **becomeFirstResponder**
>
> Notifies the receiver that it’s about to become
> first responder in its NSWindow.
>
> [...]
>
> Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make
> an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using:  FakturaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FakturaAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
[appDelegate.window makeFirstResponder:self.invoiceCredit];  instead of becomeFirstResponder, and it still doesnt work.

Comment: This saved my day, +1