# Setting initialFirstResponder in a storyboarded OSX app

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard, first-responder

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7263482/325366), I'm trying to set the first responder to the first of three `NSTextField`s in a very simple app. The advice there (set the `Window`'s first responder in interface builder) doesn't seem to apply anymore, at least not when Storyboards are involved. The `Window` object does indeed have an `initialFirstResponder` outlet, but I can find no way of setting it via drag, ctrl-drag etc., in either direction to/from the NSTextField.

The structure IB has provided me with comprises a Window Controller Scene (itself just an empty window) linked to a View Controller Scene (which in turn contains my set of `NSTextField`s and labels).

My suspicion is that there's some default assumption/association that Xcode's baked into my app that causes the Window controller to automatically load a particular view at runtime, and that's why it's not possible to bind an initial responder that it doesn't know about at build time. Which then leaves me wondering which lifecycle call on which object is the right point to be calling `self.view.window.initialFirstResponder = myTextField` before it's too late, and how to most correctly gain access to that object. `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` in the View Controller feel right, but neither seem to reliably have any effect (the initially active `NSTextField` varies from run to run, sometimes appearing to track code changes, but either times not).

I've posted the code so far on [GitHub](https://github.com/azureblue75/initialFirstResponder)

Answer (score 3):

`initialFirstResponder` is only applied when the NSWindow first appears on the screen. As per the Xcode docs:

```
`NSWindow initialFirstResponder`
The view that’s made first responder (also called the key view) the first time the window is placed onscreen.
```

If you want to set something as first responder then you need to invoke:

swift:      `yourTextField.becomeFirstresponder()`

Obj-C:      `[yourTextField becomeFirstresponder];`

Hope the helps!

Ade

*edit*

I literally shaved your .m down to a few lines:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @implementation ViewController

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    -(void)viewWillAppear{
        [super viewWillAppear];
        //[self.userTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.pathTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    #pragma mark - Connection actions

    - (IBAction)connectClicked:(id)sender {

    }

    - (IBAction)cancelClicked:(id)sender {
        // Tell the app delegate (once we've actually got a pointer to it) that we want to exit
    //    [self.delegate exitApplication];
    }



    @end
```

My fault! Sorry, viewWillAppear (just before the view actually shows up) is where you put becomeFirstResponder..

Apologies for the mistake!

Comment: Yeh, that's why I was wondering at which point in the app lifecycle it was possible to programmatically set the window's initialFirstResponder - I'm not up to speed on app, window, view and controller lifecycle in a Storyboard world. Also, that's not the right call. From the docs : "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.". becomeFirstResponder is a method views can implement to refuse becoming firstResponder. Still, makeFirstResponder doesn't work for me either!

Comment: personally I either invoke it on init or viewDidLoad:. At either which way provided that the control (NSTextField etc..) is bound to an @IBOutlet properly, then you can easily call self.whateverControl.becoemFirstRsponder() at the init() stage or viewDidLoad() stage.. Either of which happen WAY before the view heir achy actually takes effect.

Comment: makeFirstResponder returns NO for me from viewDidLoad

Comment: In the viewDidLoad query: myControl.refusesFirstResponder (boolean value)... This is settable in IB. It's about 2/3 the way down the Attributes Inspector of the control...

Comment: prior to querying it, if it is set to "false" / "NO" then [myControl setRefusesFirstResponder: NO]; or myControl.refusesFirstreponder = false

Comment: refuseFirstResponder is un-checked in the IB inspector for all fields

Comment: can you post it on Github and share the link?

Comment: Let us know :) It's probably one of the annoying quirks that Xcode exhibits by foraging away things in "impossible to find" areas... :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101487/discussion-between-chris-and-adrian-sluyters).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the solution. `becomeFirstResponder` is for asking a view if it is willing to be firstResponder (and as per the docs, not for us to call anyway), not for setting it as firstResponder. In my experience, the actual firstResponder is semi-random. It may look right, and it may not change for several runs/builds, but a clean and rebuild is likely to cause it to change (even with no code change).

Comment: [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1526750-becomefirstresponder?language=objc): Use the NSWindow [`makeFirstResponder:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419366-makefirstresponder?language=objc) method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.